# Customize the maximum width of the Firefox sidebar?

Tags: sidebar, firefox-quantum

I have Firefox Quantum web-browser version 57.0.2 (64-bit) in Windows 7.

The `Sidebar`, unfortunately, has a maximum width of about 540 pixels.

I tried to increase this constraint by going to `about:config` and searching for "sidebar". Then I changed the setting **devtools.toolbox.sidebar.width;500** to a value of **600**. Then I restarted Firefox. But it did not work.

So how can I increase the maximum width of the sidebar?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

1. Firefox menu -> Help -> Troubleshooting Information -> Profile folder -> Open folder
2. There should be folder named `chrome` (all lowercased). If it's missing, create it.
3. In said `chrome` folder, there's `userChrome.css` file. If it does not exist, create it.
4. Open this file with any text editor.
5. In this file, if there is no CSS rule `#sidebar`, create it:

```css
/* remove maximum/minimum width restriction of sidebar */
#sidebar-box {
  max-width: none !important;
  min-width: 0px !important;
}
```

6. Restart Firefox

Comment: Confirmed in FF 66: No config settings work, but  this method does. No way to improve it.

Comment: Did not work on FF 70.0.1.

Comment: Since version 69 and later, Firefox does not load userChrome.css by default. To make it effective again, open about:config in Firefox and set the preference `toolkit.legacyUserProfileCustomizations.stylesheets` to true

Comment: Does not seem to work on FF 71.

Comment: How do you guys know all of this stuff wth?

Comment: Works in FF84(64bit) together with mini's suggestion above for changing the about:config toolkit to 'true' (default was 'false')

Comment: Works in FF95.0.2(64bit) together with mini's suggestion above for changing the about:config toolkit to 'true' (default was 'false')

Comment: @ofer.sheffer (96.0) `tookit` didn't exist so I created it as Boolean and set it to True. I don't understand mini's suggestion, as I have no `toolkit.legacyUserProfileCustomizations` and can't see a way to create it so it can contain a `stylesheets` — I can only make it a simple value. An ideas?

Comment: Since version 107.0.1, there's a new name to the css property. Thank you @overcast75 for the updated note. Now it should be #sidebar-box. I added the new property into the css file, restarted and it worked.

Comment: @55Cancri You can use CTRL+SHIFT+ALT+i to inspect the browser chrome (inspect Firefox itself). Int there you can see both interface elements and default CSS for the GUI.

Answer (score 7):

Looks like this tag has had its name changed recently.  The new tag is:

```
#sidebar-box {
    max-width: none !important;
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the updated note. I mentioned you on a comment with the original answer and +1 your comment.

Comment: TY, and noted min-width also works the same; " min-width: 20px !important; "

Answer (score 0):

- locate your profile folder https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/profiles-where-firefox-stores-user-data
  -if there is no chrome folder inside download from this link http://franklion.co.uk/GEN-LINKS/chrome.zip
- edit the userChrome.css file

  /* remove maximum/minimum width restriction of sidebar */
  #sidebar {
  max-width: none !important;
  min-width: 0px !important;
  }

reload the browser

Comment: How is this better than accepted answer?

Comment: there have been changes in how to locate the profile folder for some firefox versions